# Complex group representations as an enriched category?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, enriched-category-theory, equivariant-maps

In my lecture notes it says:

> ‘Complex representations of a given group G, together with intertwiners, form a category enriched over the complex numbers.’

Is it true that the category is enriched over the complex numbers?
Why?

In a specific case this is true, namely:
I know that by Schur’s lemma given a simple complex representation $M$ of a group $G$ any intertwiner $\phi$: $M$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ is a multiple of the identity. How to proceed from here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this really is just straight from the definitions. All spaces of homomorphisms are easily seen to be vector spaces, and all the necessary conditions seem straight forward, unless I am forgetting some technical condition that is less so.

Comment: Maybe I know where my irritation comes from:
Does ‘category enriched over the field of complex numbers’ actually mean ‘category enriched over the category of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces’?

Comment: Yes, that is what is usually meant (also usually called being $\mathbb{C}$-linear).

Comment: Then the statement indeed follows from the definitions, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tobias Kildetoft mentioned in the comments:
The expression ‘category enriched over the complex numbers’ refers to the ‘category enriched over the category of ℂ-vector spaces‘. This was not clear to me.

With that knowledge, the statement quoted above follows directly from the definitions.